# request all the permission declared in the manifest file

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, permissions

am building android app with xamarin the problem am not that familiar with c#... so am trying to make my app request  all  the permission that i already declared in the manifest file at once
i tried this one but it request only the camera permission

```
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) ==(int)Permission.Granted) 
{
// We have permission, go ahead and use the camera.
} 
else 
{
// Camera permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.
}
```

how to make this code request all the declared permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.Camera}, 1);
```

You can request more permissions you want in the array. Also, note that 1 is a request code.

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int)) for more information.

Comment: U mean I have to write all the permissions? In the array?

Comment: What about the request code... Is it int 1 the same or it change with every permission

Comment: You can set it to any value you want regardless of permissions (1 is commonly used).

Comment: Can u give me an example of 3 or permission in the array please

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can refer to the offical document: [Permissions In Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows).

And there is a sample about this, you can check it here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android-m/RuntimePermissions.

If you want to define more than two permissions , you can refer to the following code snippets(here we want to read and write cotacts in our device):

```
    /**
    * Id to identify a contacts permission request.
    */
    static readonly int REQUEST_CONTACTS = 1;

    /**
    * Permissions required to read and write contacts. Used by the ContactsFragment.
    */
    static string[] PERMISSIONS_CONTACT = {
        Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts,
        Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts
    };

    public void ShowContacts (View v)
    {
        Log.Info (TAG, "Show contacts button pressed. Checking permissions.");

        // Verify that all required contact permissions have been granted.
        if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission (this, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts) != (int)Permission.Granted
            || ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission (this, Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts) != (int)Permission.Granted) {
            // Contacts permissions have not been granted.
            Log.Info (TAG, "Contact permissions has NOT been granted. Requesting permissions.");
            RequestContactsPermissions ();
        } else {
            // Contact permissions have been granted. Show the contacts fragment.
            Log.Info (TAG, "Contact permissions have already been granted. Displaying contact details.");
            ShowContactDetails ();
        }
    }
```

Method: `RequestContactsPermissions`

```
    void RequestContactsPermissions ()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (this, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts)
            || ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (this, Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts)) {

            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example, if the request has been denied previously.
            Log.Info (TAG, "Displaying contacts permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            // Display a SnackBar with an explanation and a button to trigger the request.
            Snackbar.Make (layout, Resource.String.permission_contacts_rationale,
                Snackbar.LengthIndefinite).SetAction (Resource.String.ok, new Action<View> (delegate(View obj) {
                    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions (this, PERMISSIONS_CONTACT, REQUEST_CONTACTS);
                })).Show ();
        } else {
            // Contact permissions have not been granted yet. Request them directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions (this, PERMISSIONS_CONTACT, REQUEST_CONTACTS);
        }
    }
```

Method `OnRequestPermissionsResult`

```
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
         if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACTS) {
            Log.Info (TAG, "Received response for contact permissions request.");

            // We have requested multiple permissions for contacts, so all of them need to be
            // checked.
            if (PermissionUtil.VerifyPermissions (grantResults)) {
                // All required permissions have been granted, display contacts fragment.
                Snackbar.Make (layout, Resource.String.permission_available_contacts, Snackbar.LengthShort).Show ();
            } else {
                Log.Info (TAG, "Contacts permissions were NOT granted.");
                Snackbar.Make (layout, Resource.String.permissions_not_granted, Snackbar.LengthShort).Show ();
            }

        } else {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

More more details, you can check sample: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android-m/RuntimePermissions .